# cauchy product of two series diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be $a_n=b_n=\frac {(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ and $c_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k} $ Show that the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ converge, but their cauchy produkt $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n$ diverges.

I've showed so far, that $\frac {(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ converges, but how can i show that their cauchy product $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n$ diverges?

Comment: You can use the comparison test with the harmonic series, to show it diverges.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279890/prove-the-divergence-of-cauchy-product-of-convergent-series-a-n-b-n-dfra?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\displaystyle c_n = (-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)(n-k+1)}}$.  Since $(k+1)(n-k+1) < (n+1)^2$, $\displaystyle |c_n| > \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n+1} = 1$.  So $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n c_n$ diverges.

Comment: If the series alternates in sign, this is not enough to prove divergence.

Comment: Eh?  The terms in the series don't even go to $0$, so the series can't converge.

Comment: Right.  I was still on Noble's "hint" of comparison with harmonic series.